# selenium Не работает на разных сайтах

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

При попытке обратиться к вот этому сайту:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
    try:
        driver.get('https://hemero.ru/ironage/results.php')
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
```

Всё отлично, но если попробовать обратиться к вот этому сайту то будет ошибка Message: invalid argument
(Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
try:
    driver.get('vk.com')
    time.sleep(5)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

и хотелось бы узнать, всегда в начале работы кода появляется надпись:
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

Answer (score 1):

Я понял что я сделал не так, я просто забыл добавить https в начало. Ужасный фейл